# Extra space from line-height when vertically aligning things with CSS

Tags: css

I often have to vertically align an image with a block of text next to it.

Like so:
[image]

It the problem is that because of the line-height of the text, there is the appearance of an extra space above the text:

[image]

I can't just remove the line-height because this is a multiline text block that needs a luxuriously large line height.

The only solution I've come up with is to apply a  `margin-top: -5px` to the top of the text so it becomes optically aligned with the image.

However this seems like a brittle solution since any change to the line-height of the page will throw off the alignment.

Is there a more bulletproof solution?

Comment: You can define the margin using em or rem, but CSS isn't exactly typography-savvy.

Comment: Wrap both of them into a container with the specific `top and bottom margins` set and remove the texts' `line-height`

Comment: Have you tried the infamous: display:inline-block ?

Comment: Setting `vertical-align: text-top` on the img may do what you want.

Comment: @HonoreDoktorr is correct, http://jsfiddle.net/wq46xs5v/ I tested on FF only but I think it requires a certain html structure

Answer (score 2):

*style the text as you will..*

And just wrap a `div` around that area of text, to define where you want this area to be on the page.

*(IMO more stable / semantic / and cross browser friendly then styling `<p>` or `<span>` tags alone for positioning.)*

```
<article class="cooltext">

<span class="nacholibre">one time at band camp...</span>

</article>
```

**css**

```
.cooltext { 
   margin-top:-4px; // where you want this in the page
   width: 200px; // however in relation to layout
   height: 150px; // however in relation to layout
}


.nacholibre { 
   line-height: 12px; // text formatting
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this have the same issue still? The text will be misaligned when the line-height changes

Comment: Well the idea is you move wrapper div closer to the element above. Less space is shown. IMO this is a more stable and cross-browser friendly solution then margin-top: -4px on the <p> or <span> tag.

Comment: Yea I think `vertical-align: text-top;` is the way to go

Comment: On the <p> or <span> or other global tag?

Comment: See my answer's fiddles

Comment: But your basically suggesting, to style image tags

Comment: In the simple example yes style the img tag but in a real world situation I would probably add a class and put the style on the class. It all depends on the amount of usage needed

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work as @HonoreDoktorr mentioned in the comments, using `vertical-align: text-top` is the proper way to align it. This style needs to be added to the `img` tag or a css class on the image tag. See examples of its application

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Here are 2 examples of using different html structure

http://jsfiddle.net/wq46xs5v/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/wq46xs5v

These code might resemble what you have

```
<div>
    <div class="image"><img src="http://zoarchurch.co.uk/content/pages/uploaded_images/91.png" /></div>

    <div class="text">dfgdfg</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
div {
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
}
.image, .text {
    float: left;
}
```

The magic here is `vertical-align: text-top;`. I put the style on the `img` tag but you can easily add a class to the image that needs it so not all images have that style. Note the `line-height` is set on the div containing the image and the text so they will match up correctly. Tested on FF and chrome

You can also take a look http://www.brunildo.org/test/va_lineheight.html for a good visualization of the vertical alignment

Answer (score 0):

Select p:nth-child(2) and add the line-height so the first p will not have it.

Comment: little clunky just for text formatting, don't you think?

Comment: True but most of CSS is clunky just so happens that's how I figured it out. I didn't claim to be an expert just wanted to give my cup of tea.

Comment: But the first paragraph won't have the same spacing as the rest if it is more than 1 line and the width of the browser will determine when the paragraph wraps

Comment: True @Huangism , no one knows has a better answer :)